# mysqldump command to replicate backup created by MySQL Administrator

Tags: backup, mysql, database-backups

I am in charge of managing database backups for a MySQL database. This is something that I have not had to do in the past, and I am working toward a system of automatic backups that are compressed nightly.

Currently, the nightly backup is covering all databases in MySQL. The databasse are being backed up using MySQL Administrator with the following settings under the "Advanced Options" tab:

In the "Backup Execution Method" box, the radio button for InnoDB Online Backup is selected, as well as the check box for Complete backup. In the "Output File Options" box, the Backup Type is "SQL Files" with the following boxes checked: Add DROP Statements, Complete INSERTs, Comment, and Disable keys.

This backup is set to run daily and the resulting sql file is roughly 3.5GB.

I want to automate the process of backing up the database followed immediately by compressing the sql file using gzip and deleting the sql file (for storage space savings).

However, when I attempt to use mysqldump, the file that is created is nearly 1.5GB smaller than the MySQL Administrator backup. My command dumped all databases using switches that match those listed above, but the result, as I said above, was a much smaller file.

**Could someone show me the proper mysqldump command to use in order to output a file that matches the file that MySQL Administrator creates using the options shown above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
mysqldump --all-databases --complete-insert -p > databasebackup.sql
```

see the [mysqldump Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: I appreciate the response. I wrote this late last night and I guess I forgot to actually type out the command that I used with mysqldump. Here it is: mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --result-file="c:\temp\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql" --all-databases --add-drop-table --comments --complete-insert --disable-keys

It looks as though my command may have been formatted wrong. I didn't receive any sort of error doing it as shown.

I do see though, that the manual shows the options directly after the mysqldump command. I should stop attempting new things while very tired.